# How to prove $a \lt b$ for all $a \in A, b \in B$ implies $\sup A \leq \inf B$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

If $A, B$ are two non empty sets of real numbers and for every $a$ from $A$ and $b$ from $B$

> $a < b$,

how can I prove that

> $\sup A \leq \inf B$?

Comment: This is not true; you can only say that $supA \le infB$.

Comment: This question is part of a series that sound like homework problems.

Comment: Looking at your history this is a homework problem!

Comment: -1.  Do your own homework, or ask conceptual questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is true. Let $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,2)$ then $\operatorname{sup}A=1$ and $\operatorname{inf}B=1$ but $A$ and $B$ satisfy your conditions.

Comment: The conditions are violated because 1 is in A and is not strictly less than all elements of B.

Comment: @whuber 1 is in A=(0,1)? Shurely shome mishtake?

Comment: @Bob: Thank you: I was misreading these as doubleton sets, not intervals.  Alext87's answer is a good one.

Comment: @alext87, this question is absolutely correct. In A=(0,1) and B=(1,2), supA=infB. The question wants us to prove that supA<=infB. (It includes '=' case).

Comment: @Nipun: The question was *edited* after alext87's answer was given (and presumably accepted), as shows the edit history of the question.

Answer (score 6):

With the edited problem: if $a\lt b$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, why is it that $\sup(A)\leq\inf(B)$? Is every element of $A$ a lower bound for $B$? If so, what does that tell you about the elements of $A$ relative to $\inf(B)$? And given that, what does *that* tell you about $\sup(A)$?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the solution:

Let us suppose that $\sup(A) > \inf(B)$. So, there exists some $x∈A$, such that $\inf(B) < x$. Again, as $\inf(B)< x$, there exists $y∈B$, such that $y<x$. which is a contradiction as we have been given that $A<B$ (i.e, $x<y$ for all $x∈A$, $y∈B$). So, our assuption that $\sup(A) > \inf(B)$ is WRONG. So, $\sup(A) \leq \inf(B)$. 
Hence Proved...... :)

Comment: I have converted the first part of your answer into a comment to alext87 (look above). Because you do not have 50 reputation points yet, [you can only comment on your own questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757). So, you didn't do anything wrong; the "add comment" button will only appear for you once you gain 50 points. Here is an [explanation of reputation points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238).

Answer (score 4):

Consider $b\in B$, by hypothesis is a upper bound of $A$, so by definition of sup (the least upper bound), $\sup A\leq b,$ $ \forall b\in B$. Now the $\sup A$ is a lower bound of $B$, so by defnition of inf(the grater lower bound), $\sup A\leq \inf B$ .

Comment: By assumption we have  $\forall a \in A, \forall b \in B$  it holds that $a<b$.

 So every single $b$ in $B$ is an upper bound for the set $A$, we know in particular that for any $b \in B$, we have $$\sup(A)\leq b $$ since the supremum is the smallest of upper bounds. We now also realise that $\sup(A)$ is a lower bound for the set $B$, we thus realise that:
$$ \sup(A) \leq \inf(B)$$
As the infimum is the greatest of all lower bounds.
 $\square$